# Может ли интерфейс IModelValidator быть использован для создания валидатора на уровне модели(класса)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp

Я хотел бы организовать проверку полей моделей так, чтобы вся валидация всех полей класса модели происходила в одном классе валидатора, который бы в свою очередь возвращал массив объектов с описанием найденных ошибок, если они есть.

Я нашел три способа валидации:

1. Используя класс - ValidationAttribute;

Данный метод мне показался неуместным поскольку он предполагает использование одного атрибута для валидации одного поля. Я же хочу создать класс который будет валидировать все необходимые поля сразу, при этом вызвращая информацию об ошибках валидации для каждого поля.

2. Используя интерфейс - IValidatableObject

Это способ удовлетворяет мою потребность в одновременной проверке всех полей и предоставлении всех найденных ошибок валидации, но мне не нравится идея того что реализация валидации должна при этом находится непосредственно в классе модели.

3. Используя интерфейс - IModelValidator

Используя интерфейс IModelValidator можно создать пользовательский атрибут для валидации данных модели, который может быть применен к свойству модели:

```
public class LanguageValidator : Attribute, IModelValidator
{
    public IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(ModelValidationContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, этот способ предполагает возможность создания валидатора в виде атрибута с возможностью валидации всех полей класса и возможностью возвращения соответствующего массива найденных ошибок. 
Во всех найденных мной примерах данный способ применялся только к полям класса.

**Подскажите**:

- Можно ли используя интерфейс IModelValidator создавать атрибуты валидации которые бы применялись не к свойствам модели а к самому классу модели?
- Если какой то способ создать атрибут валидации, который бы позволял внутри себя выполнять валидацию сразу всех полей класса, при этом возвращая массив всех найденных ошибок для каждого из полей?

Comment: вы DTO хотите этим валидировать или бизнес логику?

Comment: @tym32167 - Model - и. Хотел использовать один атрибут на один класс для валидации всех нужных мне полей, с возможностью получения массива ошибок + что бы сохранилась возможность взаимодействия со свойством "ModelState.IsValid" в методах действия контроллеров.